# What is essential non-isolated singularity, of $f(z) = \sin\left(\frac{1}{\cos(\frac{1}{z})}\right)$.

Tags: complex-analysis, definition, singularity

Let a function $f$ be defined as $f(z) = \sin\left(\dfrac{1}{\cos\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)}\right)$.

I need to check what type of singularity it has at $z = 0$?

I found it is non-isolated as it is a limit point of the set of singularities.

Now in the answer key, It is written that it is essential and non-isolated.

Now this confuses me as I have read that essential singularity is a type of isolated singularity. I even googled and saw the same.

Can anyone throw some light on the meaning of essential non-isolated singularity?

It would be a great help.

Comment: I have no idea, I have always seen it as you say. Your professor is free to define their own notations and conventions within their class if you can go back and look in your notes (and they may have had a legitimate pedagogical reason to do so), but it is dangerous when these do not align with the rest of the world.

Comment: Did you read my reply? Did it help?

Comment: @Diger..Sorry..Didn't read it yet..Will notify you when I do

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(z)$ be holomorphic on an annulus with laurent-expansion $$f(z)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} a_n z^n \, .$$ $f(z)$ is said to have an essential singularity at $z=0$ if $$\limsup_{n\rightarrow -\infty} |a_{n}| \neq 0 \, .$$
The crucial point of an essential singularity is that $f(z)$ takes every value in $\mathbb{C}$ in the vicinity of $z=0$ (with at most 1 exception). Now if $f(z)$ takes every such value in the vicinity of $z=0$, then $1/f(z)$ takes every such value too (with said 1 exception). Therefore $1/f(z)$ has an essential singularity at $z=0$. Now if $g(z)$ is entire, its image covers $\mathbb{C}$ entirely and therefore $g(1/f(z))$ takes every value in $\mathbb{C}$ in the vicinity of $z=0$ (again the exception is passed on).

In your special case $g(z)=\sin(z)$ and $f(z)=\cos(1/z)$. It is non-isolated, since you actually have a multitude of such singularities in the vicinity of $z=0$ e.g. at $z_n=\frac{1}{\pi/2+n\pi}$ where $\cos(1/z)$ has a simple zero that is inside the $\sin$ (just like $\sin(1/z)$ is essential at $z=0$).

Comment: If 1/f(z) takes every value in the vicinity of zero then why does it have an essential singularity at $z = 0$

Comment: If $g$ is entire why does its image cover the entire complex plane

Comment: @Gitika: Yes you are right: with 1 exception.

Comment: Is it clear now?

Comment: No..If g is entire why does its image cover the entire complex plane ?

Comment: You can consider the following cases. 1) $g$ is a polynomial in which case it is clear except when $g$ is a constant (the 1 exception). 2) $g$ is not a polynomial s.t. it has the Laurent-series $g(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n$ with infinitely many $a_n\neq0$. Introduce $z=1/w$ and so $g(1/w)$ has an essential sing. at $w=0$ (corresponding to complex infinity in the variable $z$).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard_theorem